# Nominatim - Postgres DB growing very fast in size when doing the daily updates

Tags: postgresql, diskspace, nominatim, wal

I have done a full import with the planet from OSM website and scheduled the updates to run daily on a cronjob.

But I have noticed that the disk usage is growing very fast in size on a daily basis.
When running the command df -h, I have noticed that every day the disk size grows about 1GB. Not sure if this command does some round up, but even so this size seems very huge.

I have a disk with 1TB free, but this would mean that the disk would be full in about 3 years.

I have tried to inspect the folders under /var/lib/postgresql/<version>/<cluster> and it seems that the folders that concur to this size increase are the folders pg_wal and base/16390.

The folder base/16390 has many files with 1GB each and the folder pg_wal has about 40 something files of 16MB each.

I don't know which files are safe to remove or if there are some configs for the postgresql.conf file that would prevent this huge increase in size each day.

Also don't know if this has to do with some backups or logs that postgres does by default, but I would like to also reduce those backups and logs to a minimum.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without knowing anything about what is happing, a timespan of 3 years is not my definition of "very fast". On topic: Is autovacuum running and doing its job?

Comment: On the file postgresql.conf I have autovacuum set to on.

Comment: And is it running? Check the view pg_stat_user_tables to see if your tables are vacuumed, how many updates are done, how many dead tuples you have, etc.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, that table shows 0 rows, so maybe the autovacuum is not running.
How can I put the autovacuum running?